# Printing 0 to 50 inclusive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why is this code not printing 0 to 50 inclusive?

```
i = 0
until i <= 50 do
  print i
  i += 1
end
```

Comment: I'm no Ruby expert, but "until" implies to me that it will stop looping when the condition is true.  And `i <= 50` is immediately true.

Comment: BTW, the Ruby [documentation for `until`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-until+Loop) contains an example to print the numbers 0 to 11.

Comment: user3874912, The piling-on of `-1`'s is what happens when someone posts a head-slapper question and then walks away. Best to hang around for at least a few minutes.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Either use

```
until i > 50 do
  # ...
end
```

or

```
while i <= 50 do
  # ...
end
```

Here's a more "Ruby like" example:

```
(0..50).each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Ugh.

```
i = 0
until i <= 50 do
  print i
  i += 1
end
```

That would generate 51 iterations because you're starting at 0 and trying to run until 50 is reached, except that `until` is "notting" your condition. If you want to loop perhaps `while` would be a better test:

```
i = 0
while i <= 50 do
  print i
  i += 1
end
>> 01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950nil
```

But, even with `while` there are still 51 values being output:

```
i = 0
output = []
while i <= 50 do
  output << i
  i += 1
end
output.size # => 51
```

If you want to loop 50 times, why not use:

```
50.times do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Or:

```
50.times { |i| puts i }
```

Comment: love the 50.times thing . for me , it's the cleanest way

Answer (score 2):

Change `until` to `while`. `until` is basically the same thing as `while`, but the conditional is inverted.

Comment: @user3874912 By doing what I said...?

Comment: i know but its asks to use until

Comment: @user3874912 Then change the conditional to `i > 50`, the inverse of `i <= 50`

Answer (score 2):

Another iterative method to use would be `upto`:

```
0.upto(50) do |i|
  puts i
end
```

I really love this method for quick number iterations.  It's super idiomatic (it does what it says) and it's inclusive of both start and end values so you don't have to calculate/account for an exclusive end val.

Answer (score 1):

`until` stops executing when the condition it has is true. Because it is true from the beginning, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Just swap the comparison operators.

```
i = 0
until i > 50 do
  print i
  i += 1
end
```

You could also do

```
i = 0
while i <= 50 do
  print i
  i += 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use Idiomatic Ruby

Other answers have addressed why your original code doesn't work, and have pointed out the logic error in your conditional. However, it's worth noting that a more idiomatic way to do what you're doing would avoid the conditional altogether. For example:

```
(1..50).each { |i| pp i }
```

Comment: Quick note: if you are using irb instead of pry as your REPL, you may need to `require 'pp'` from the standard library's [PP module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html) for this answer to work. Otherwise, just use `puts` instead of `pp`.

Answer (score 0):

This works. ;)

```
i = 1
while i < 51 do
  print i
  i += 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you have the comparison sing backwards

you want to do something like:

```
i = 0
until i >= 50 do
  print i
  i += 1
end
```

you can take a look at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-until+Loop for more info